# How can you determine how to place coins on a clock?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Say you are given a set of coins such as 4 10¢, 4 5¢, and 4 1¢.

You are asked to place these coins on a 12-hour analog clock face, where the next coin you place must be placed at X hours after the previous coin, where X is the value of the previous coin.

So if you place a 1¢ on 12, the next coin you place goes at 1. If you place a 5¢ on 1, the next coin you place goes at 6. And so on.

How can you maximize the number of coins that can be placed on the clock before the next coin would have to be placed in a slot that is already taken?

This is a problem I came across which I have been unable to solve except via exhaustive search. If the inputs are made to be arbitrary, exhaustive search fails quickly-- say it's an arbitrary number of coins of arbitrary various known denominations, with an arbitrary number of hours on the clock. Then you can't do exhaustive search anymore, because it becomes factorial time and fails on basis of excessive computational time requirements.

Comment: If you always have to start with the first coin at 12 there are no more than 4*4*4 = 64 solutions. Did you try an exhaustive search? Even if the first coin can start anywhere there are still no more than 12*4*4*4 = 768 solutions. Just try them all see which is best.

Comment: I should have been clear I was looking for a non-exhaustive solution; the real problem is if the inputs are arbitrary. Say you have an arbitrary number of coins of arbitrary various known denominations, and arbitrary number of hours displayed on the clock face.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter where the first coin starts  since which hour you place a coin on has no role in subsequent placements-- only the number of hours on the clock total, which controls how much space there is before you start passing previous coin placements, so the 768 figure is not applicable. The solution would be the same starting on 1 o'clock as on 5, 7, or 12.

Comment: can you have coins whose jump distance is greater than the counts in the clock?

Comment: Wouldn't such a coin be reduceable to `denominationOfThatCoin % hoursOnClock` ? So let's say yes, it's possible.

Comment: Sorry to pester, i am working through possibilities, but... i do not follow why a well built exhaustive search would ever fail... Are you saying it fails for computational time reasons?  IE a function which takes in as arguments the clock size and then a list of coins and then does a tree search... was simple to write and tbh im quite certain that it would never fail to determine the best answer

Comment: Yes, computational time reasons. Pretty sure that becomes factorial time with arbitrary inputs.

Comment: This looks like a variant of the Josephus problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: @m69: I think one very important difference between this problem and the Josephus problem is that the Josephus problem removes the executed from consideration at each step. (So, "skip 3 people" means "skip 3 not-yet-executed people, as well as any already-executed people in between".) That makes the Josephus problem more obviously amenable to dynamic programming (even if it didn't have a closed-form solution): after you've executed one person, you've reduced the problem by one. But with the OP's problem here, you still need to keep track of all the occupied positions.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than backtracking unless there are more restrictions.

Comment: @maraca can you show what such a solution would look like in an answer? It's not a type of algorithm I have a lot of experience implementing.

Comment: It's going to be a couple days before I can examine the new solutions but it will happen-- I've got a lot going on right now. I really appreciate the interest in the question though.

Comment: Are you more interested in a single solution (first found), or all correct (max) solutions?

Comment: Correct solution(s)~ the most coins you can place, the max.

Answer (score 3):

As maraca mentioned probably there isn't a much better solution than backtracking without more restrictions. Maybe with a larger number of coins of given denominations space can be covered with 'patterns'. Like coins `[5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, x]` cover first 8 places and next coin is placed in similar location as first one. So the process can be repeated if there are enough coins.

Number of possible coin combinations in this case is not large at all. It is `12! / (4! * 4! * 4!) = 34650`. For sure number explodes with larger parameters. Here is simple python code that solves 3 times larger problem which has possible coin combinations [`3*10^15`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=36!%20%2F%20(12!%20*%2012!%20*%2012!)).

```
max_positions = []
max_order = None

def add_coin(coins, position, coin_order, occupied_positions, num_hours):
    global max_positions, max_order
    if position in occupied_positions or not coins:
        # Can't place on that position or there is nothing more to place
        if len(occupied_positions) > len(max_positions):
            max_positions = occupied_positions
            max_order = coin_order
        return not coins  # if all is covered return true to stop search
    #
    for c, num_coins in coins:  # Try each coin
        # Copy coins to new list and remove one used
        c_coins = [x for x in coins if x[0] != c]
        if num_coins > 1:
            c_coins.append((c, num_coins-1))
        # Next iteration
        if add_coin(c_coins,
                 (position + c) % num_hours,
                 coin_order + [c],
                 occupied_positions + [position],
                 num_hours):
            return True

def solve_coins(coins, num_hours):
    global max_positions, max_order
    max_positions = []
    max_order = None
    add_coin(coins, 0, [], [], num_hours)
    print len(max_positions), max_positions, max_order

solve_coins([(1, 4), (5, 4), (10, 4)], 12)
solve_coins([(1, 8), (5, 8), (10, 8)], 24)
solve_coins([(1, 12), (5, 12), (10, 12)], 36)
```

output:

```
12 [0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 9, 7, 5, 10, 11] [1, 5, 10, 10, 1, 5, 1, 10, 10, 5, 1, 5]
24 [0, 1, 6, 16, 17, 3, 4, 14, 19, 5, 15, 20, 21, 2, 7, 8, 13, 18, 23, 9, 10, 11, 12, 22] [1, 5, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 10, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10]
36 [0, 1, 6, 16, 17, 22, 23, 28, 2, 12, 13, 18, 19, 29, 34, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 21, 31, 5, 15, 20, 30, 35, 4, 14, 24, 25, 26, 27, 32, 33, 7] [1, 5, 10, 1, 5, 1, 5, 10, 10, 1, 5, 1, 10, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 10, 5]
```

Comment: Really nice answer, as far as I can tell. I can see that it's a backtracking approach, but I can't figure out how to determine the runtime. I also can't quite tell how the backtracking approach differs from exhaustive search-- in both cases aren't you trying all options, exploring each one until it fails, meanwhile keeping track of the best candidate you've found so far? I'm thinking this still has a worst-case runtime of `O(N!)`, does that seem right?

Comment: Yes, backtracking tries each combination from begining and if it fails return one step back and tries next one. Like coins 1,5,1,5 place next one on 0 and there is no solution. Options after are not checked, and step back proceed with option 1,5,1,10. Running time is exponential. Number of checked options are order or two orders less than number of possible combinations of given coins. Still a lot :-)

Comment: So let's see....if there were more coins than hours on the clock, you would just have to change `return not coins` to `return len(occupied_positions) == num_hours`. And if you wanted to use the value of the coin being placed to determine position, instead of previous coin (e.g. placing a nickel means it must be 5 hours after previous coin) then you change...uh....`occupied_positions + [position]` to be `occupied_positions + [(position + c) % num_hours]`, I think. Just exploring variants/constraints.

Comment: I am going to leave the question open for now in case other people have ideas about how to solve it, but in the near future you are likely to become the accepted answer if a better one does not emerge. Nicely solved!

Comment: Why would someone downvote this, particularly without leaving any comment?

Comment: *I didn't downvote* but I do not see how this is anything more than a recursion based exhaustive search... (I do see that options are not checked, but this still doesn't seem to be the target *at least in my understanding* of your question)

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear This is exhaustive search. I don't think (hope) this is final answer to the question. Question is nice, and it would be perfect if there is a clever solution to it. Maybe I be mistaken, but it seems to me that downvote is automatically set by SO. It seems to me that I get few downvotes on answers where I upvoted question. That makes sense to prevent collaborative reputation building.

Comment: That is not a thing.  I am 100% sure SO does not downvote an answer submitted by you for any reason, it is all peers.

Answer (score 3):

```java
// Expressing the coins as a list of buckets with the same modulo allows
// you to efficiently find the next coin to test and you don't start to
// calculate with the first penny and then do the same again starting
// with the second penny (or a 13-coin on a 12-clock), it is basically the same.
// Additionally it allows to remove and insert items at the current position in O(1).
// Also reverting is much better than copying whole states on each recursive call.
private class Bucket {
    public int number;
    public LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();
    public Bucket(int number, int hours) {
        this.number = number % hours;
        numbers.add(number);
    }
}

private LinkedList<Bucket> coins; // not using interface List as you are supposed to
private LinkedList<Integer> best, current; // because of removeLast()
private boolean[] occupied;
private int hours, limit;

public List<Integer> findBest(int[] coins, int hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
    // create buckets of coins with the same modulo
    Integer[] c = Arrays.stream(coins).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
    // sort descending because a lot of small coins in a row are more likely to create
    // an impassable area on the next pass around the clock
    Arrays.sort(c, new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return Integer.compare(b.intValue() % hours, a.intValue() % hours);
        }
    });
    this.coins = new LinkedList<>();
    Bucket b = new Bucket(c[0].intValue(), hours);
    this.coins.add(b);
    int mod = c[0].intValue() % hours, coinCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
        int m = c[i].intValue() % hours;
        if (m == mod) { // same bucket
            b.numbers.add(c[i]);
        } else { // new bucket
            b = new Bucket(c[i].intValue(), hours);
            this.coins.add(b);
            mod = m;
        }
        coinCount++;
        if (mod == 0) // don't need more than one 0 value
            break;
    }
    best = new LinkedList<>();
    current = new LinkedList<>();
    occupied = new boolean[hours];
    limit = coinCount < hours ? coinCount : hours; // max coins that can be placed
    findBest(0);
    return best;
}

private void findBest(int pos) {
    if (best.size() == limit) // already found optimal solution
        return;
    if (occupied[pos] || current.size() == limit) {
        if (current.size() > best.size())
            best = (LinkedList<Integer>)current.clone();
        return;
    }
    occupied[pos] = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
        Bucket b = coins.get(i);
        current.add(b.numbers.removeLast());
        boolean removed = false;
        if (b.numbers.size() == 0) { // bucket empty
            coins.remove(i);
            removed = true;
        }
        findBest((pos + b.number) % hours);
        if (removed)
            coins.add(i, b);
        b.numbers.add(current.removeLast());
    }
    occupied[pos] = false;
}
```

Output for the given example: 10 10 5 1 1 1 5 10 10 1 5 5

---

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r1rcuz6a/3/) is a slightly more optimized version in JavaScript where the list is implemented manually, so that you can really see why removing and adding the currend bucket is O(1). Because the list is always read in order it is superior to the array in this case. Whith an array you need to shift many elements or skip a lot of empty ones, depending how you implement it, not with a list of buckets. Should be a little easier to understand than the Java code.

```js
var head, occupied, current, best, h, limit;

document.body.innerHTML = solve([1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10], 12);

function solve(coins, hours) {
    h = hours;
    coins.sort(function(a, b) {
        let x = a % hours, y = b % hours;
        if (x > y)
            return -1;
        if (x < y)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    let mod = coins[0] % hours;
    head = {num: mod, vals: [coins[0]], next: null};
    let b = head, coinCount = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < coins.length && mod != 0; i++) {
        let m = coins[i] % hours;
        if (m == mod) {
            b.vals.push(coins[i]);
        } else {
            b.next = {num: m, vals: [coins[i]], next: null};
            b = b.next;
            mod = m;
        }
        coinCount++;
    }
    limit = coinCount < hours ? coinCount : hours;
    occupied = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hours; i++)
        occupied.push(false);
    best = [];
    current = [];
    solveRec(0);
    return JSON.stringify(best);
}

function solveRec(pos) {
    occupied[pos] = true;
    let b = head, prev = null;
    while (b !== null) {
        let m = (pos + b.num) % h;
        if (!occupied[m]) {
            current.push(b.vals.pop());
            let rem = false;
            if (b.vals.length == 0) {
                if (prev == null)
                    head = b.next;
                else
                    prev.next = b.next;
                rem = true;
            }
            solveRec(m);
            if (current.length > best.length)
                best = current.slice();
            if (best.length == limit)
                return;
            if (rem) {
                if (prev == null)
                    head = b;
                else
                    prev.next = b;
            }
            b.vals.push(current.pop());
        } else if (current.length + 1 > best.length) {
            best = current.slice();
            best.push(b.vals[b.vals.length - 1]);
        }
        prev = b;
        b = b.next;
    }
    occupied[pos] = false;
}
```

Comment: Including a high-level description of your approach is usually preferred above posting just code for algorithm questions, especially language-agnostic ones (even if that code is commented).

Comment: What is your O() for this algorithm?

Comment: Next try: O((coins choose hours) * hours!), (if there are at least as many coins as hours). Although in practice it will be much faster because a lot of branches will be cut because of occupied spots, already found optimal solution or numbers that are in the same bucket. @SneakyPolarBear

Comment: If you would humor me (i intend to copy your algo into c++ so that i can learn backtracking), but could you test your algo on the following set and record how many combinations are considered (checked):  12hrs, 12 coins: (2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6)

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear How do you count the number of combinations? You mean the number of recursive calls? This should be about the same as adding the number of combinations in each iteration (but I am not sure). Will report on it. Btw. to really see the potential you would need to use (2,14,26,38,4,16,28,40,6,18,30,42).

Comment: It is both 172.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear Counter example: (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 12 hour clock, 109 calls, what do you get?

Comment: by check combo i mean specifically each time you test a modulus against clock length (ie check if the current combo is still fair)

Comment: To answer your example and then explain mine: (my algo would take hours if not days to process your example), (but what I was pointing out is that yours is dependent on the breakout case to get fast runs, ie if it can not find a max length solution, it approaches exhaustive)  to be much more specific: if your algo can not find a combo matching clock length allowing it to end prematurely, what is the complexity?  a similar but differently phrased way of asking this is, what is the complexity for your answer to find all of the combo solutions tied for longest?  (not trying to pester)

Comment: Yes I know it will look at all good cases (not all combinations because of buckets and already occupied spots). Each recursive call a modulus is built, but that is not what is expensive and wouldn't be a good measure. You would need to compare against the sum of combinations in each iteration. Checking if you can combine something equals more or less a recursive call.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear check out further optimized version, only 58 calls instead of 172. Also added JS-Fiddle so you can add your own measures.

Answer (score 0):

I am still working on this, but it is already much better than O(n!).  I will try to fit a new O() on it soon.

The concept is pretty simple, basically you create the smallest combos of numbers and then link them together into longer and longer strings of numbers until the next step is not possible.

A key to this working is that you don't track the front or end of a list of numbers, only the sum (and the inner sums due to their being calculated at earlier steps).  so long as that sum is never divisible by clock, it will remain a clean solution.

Each step attempts to "splice" the smaller combos into the next size bigger:
(1,3), (3,1) -> (1,3,1), (3,1,3)

Here is a brief example (simplified) of what the algo is doing:
clock: 4
coins: 4
coins: 1,2,3,3

***bold pass**, others are skipped for 1 of 3 reasons (not enough in population to build combo, sum divisible by clock, (in actual algo) prevent duplicates: (1,1),**(1,2)**,(1,3),**(2,1)**,(2,2),**(2,3)**,(3,1),**(3,2)**,**(3,3)**

triples:  (1,2,1), (2,1,2), (2,3,2), (3,2,3), **(1,2,3)**, (2,3,3), **(3,2,1)**, (3,3,2)

final combos:**(1,2,3,x), (3,2,1,x)**

---

This code is runnable standalone in c++ (but placeCoins is the algo):
I assume you will appropriate the algo to your purposes, but for anyone who wishes to run this cpp file, it will request clock size, coin count, and then after putting in coin count it will accept the next *coin count* number of inputs followed by enter as the coin values.  The output will show the best counts, all orders at that count, and also during the algo it will show you the number of currently processing steps (which is where you can estimate complexity/ number of combos checked to see how much faster this is than exhaustive of any kind)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//min clock size 3
vector<vector<int>> placeCoins(int _clockSize, vector<int> _coins)
{
    int totalCheckedCombos = 0;
    vector<vector<int>> coinGroups;
    vector<int> coinSet = _coins;
    sort(coinSet.begin(), coinSet.end());
    coinSet.erase(unique(coinSet.begin(), coinSet.end()), coinSet.end());

    map<int, int> coinCounts;
    for (int i = 0; i < coinSet.size(); i++)
    {
        coinCounts[coinSet.at(i)] = count(_coins.begin(), _coins.end(), coinSet.at(i));
    }

    cout << "pairs" << endl;
    //generate fair pairs of coins
    for (int i = 0; i < coinSet.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < coinSet.size(); ii++)
        {
            if ((coinSet.at(i) + coinSet.at(ii)) % _clockSize != 0)
            {
                if (i == ii)
                {
                    if (coinCounts[coinSet.at(i)] > 1)
                    {
                        coinGroups.push_back({ coinSet.at(i),coinSet.at(ii) });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    coinGroups.push_back({ coinSet.at(i),coinSet.at(ii) });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "combine" << endl;
    //iteratively combine groups of coins
    for (int comboSize = 3; comboSize < _clockSize; comboSize++)
    {
        totalCheckedCombos += coinGroups.size();
        vector<vector<int>> nextSizeCombos;
        for (int i = 0; i < coinGroups.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < coinGroups.size(); ii++)
            {
                //check combo to match  
                bool match = true;
                for (int a = 0; a < comboSize - 2; a++)
                {
                    if (coinGroups.at(i).at(a+1) != coinGroups.at(ii).at(a))
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //check sum
                if (match)
                {
                    vector<int> tempCombo = coinGroups.at(i);
                    int newVal = coinGroups.at(ii).at(coinGroups.at(ii).size()-1);
                    tempCombo.push_back(newVal);
                    if (coinCounts[newVal] >= count(tempCombo.begin(), tempCombo.end(), newVal))
                    {
                        if (accumulate(tempCombo.begin(), tempCombo.end(), 0) % _clockSize != 0)
                        {
                            nextSizeCombos.push_back(tempCombo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (nextSizeCombos.size() == 0)
        {
            //finished, no next size combos found
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << nextSizeCombos.size() << endl;
            coinGroups = nextSizeCombos;
        }
    }
    cout << "total combos checked: " << totalCheckedCombos << endl;
    return coinGroups;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int clockSize;
    int coinCount;
    vector<int> coins = {};



    cout << "enter clock size: " << endl;
    cin >> clockSize;

    cout << "count number: " << endl;
    cin >> coinCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < coinCount; i++)
    {
        int tempCoin;
        cin >> tempCoin;
        coins.push_back(tempCoin);
    }

    cout << "press enter to compute combos: " << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    vector<vector<int>> resultOrders = placeCoins(clockSize, coins);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultOrders.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << resultOrders.at(0).size()+1 << endl;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < resultOrders.at(i).size(); ii++)
        {
            cout << resultOrders.at(i).at(ii) << " , ";
        }
        cout <<"x"<< endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

ps: although I debugged this to a stable state, it still could definitely use fine tuning and optimization, but that is variable to different languages, so I just got the algo to work and called it good enough. If you see something glaringly wrong or poor form, feel free to comment and i'll fix it (or edit it directly if you want).

Comment: haha, this is way better than n!, but still definitely not n^2 yet.  I will continue trying to optimize

Comment: coinCounts is used and referenced to make sure that no combo is used which requires more than the supply of a particular demonimation.

Comment: *your are correct* as for worst case O(), I do not believe that I have achieved exponential yet, but it is much better than factorial atm.  I have tabulated and compared combos checked for this.  Currently on a log10 plot I have a slope about half way between n! and n^2

Comment: there is nothing in the logic that causes it to not work with combos longer than hours/2... in most of my testing the solution sets are in fact full fills... Perhaps you misunderstand the spicing step (where really only 1 item is added).  when i combine (1,2,3) with (2,3,4) the result is (1,2,3,4)... one more than the size of the previous step.

Comment: Currently I am trying to hash the combo checks to speed that up, but so far have not come up with a solid idea on how to reduce my combo check magnitude yet (which is the primary goal of this problem)

Comment: Ok I see, but when you add to all combos, you still need to know which numbers can be added to which combo and essentially it has exacctly the same complexity as the backtracking solution in my opinion, you are just doing it iteratively.

Comment: Actually it's worse, because the list of combos will explode and backtracking stops as soon as a solution was found, which means branches can be cut at the root, not just at the leaves.

Comment: this method is not for finding a single solution, it is for finding the full set of max length solutions.  that being said, there is inherent danger to the single solution methods of variable time, because (i don't have an example set) if you can not find a max length solution to break out of the search, then you keep looking till the end which is the complexity that i am comparing too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a greedy approach, try the maximum result of choosing a coin vs. not choosing a coin.

```
def valueOfClock(capacity, coins, n, hour):
    if (n == 0 or capacity == 0 or hour > 12):
        return 0

    # Choose next coin if value is greater than the capacity
    if (coins[n-1] > capacity):
        valueOfClock(capacity, coins, n-1, hours)

    # Choose max value of either choosing the next coin or
    # choosing the current coin
    return max(valueOfClock(capacity, coins, n-1, hours),
               valueOfClock(capacity-coins[n-1], coins, n-1, hours + coins[n-1]))
```

Comment: `hour > 12` is at odds with supporting arbitrary input. Shouldn't that be a 5th parameter to the function? Still reading through the rest of the code. I think I'm going to have to ask you to add some more text to this answer, explaining it. I'm afraid I can't quite understand your approach on my own; possibly it's too clever for me. Why do we want to check if `coins[n-1]` is greater than `capacity`? What is `n` and what would its initial value be? What is `capacity`? In my naivety I would have said this *is* a greedy approach. What would a greedy approach look like?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be returning the result of the first recursive call to `valueOfClock` in the first conditional? I'm trying to see how this solution knows when it has hit upon a slot that's already taken; I don't see how or where it's doing that.

Comment: Additionally, you have a parameter named `hour` but make several references to a parameter `hours`-- which one did you mean? It's unclear to me if you mean "the hour we're placing the coin on" or "the number of hours on the clock."

Comment: I ran this with inputs as follows -- `valueOfClock(12, [1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10], 12, 12)` and got an output of `0`. Did I misunderstand the inputs?